# How to get example.com or sub1.example.com to point to my EC2 vm?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain

I have `example.com` registered at GoDaddy (and hosted elsewhere). I created a subdomain at `sub1.example.com`.

I have a virtual linux machine running great on EC2 accessible as `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Question: How do I get `sub1.example.com` to point to my EC2 virtual machine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two way you can setup this:

1. If you have EIP configured to your EC2 instance then point your subdomain's `A` record to this EIP.
2. Instead of creating a subdomain create a `CNAME` record with name as subdomain and value as your EC2 public DNS which is `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.